# Cakephp: using $this->Component->load() in component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I want to add components in an component.

I've found this on the cake

```
$this->OneTimer = $this->Components->load('OneTimer');
$this->OneTimer->getTime();
(in the fly-mehtod)
```

But, when I try it in my controller i get the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the in the fly-method is only for controllers, and not for components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `App::uses` to import components in another component

```
App::uses('OneTimer', 'Controller/Component');
$this->OneTimer = new OneTimerComponent(new ComponentCollection());
$this->OneTimer->getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method of one component within another component using APP::import.
Try this one

```
      App::import('component', 'OneTimer');
      $this->OneTimer = new OneTimerComponent();
      $this->OneTimer->getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

It will work simply like this

```
 App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
    class CalendarComponent extends Object{
        public $components = array('NotificationManager');
        function test(){
            $this->NotificationManager->callfunction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension (you can doing so, by using the edit link underneath your post).

Comment: it is self explanatory even question is very clear so of course here component is using another component.